# Make CodeMirror highlight PHP syntax

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, editor

CodeMirror by default only highlights `mixed-html` syntax (i.e HTML, CSS, and Javascript) in Joomla. Many of us use custom plugins to run PHP inside modules and articles, but CodeMirror doesn't highlight PHP syntax at all. It becomes extremely difficult to manage modules when dealing with a lot of code. How can I make CodeMirror highlight `mixed-html` as well as PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need:

> **[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.1.html)** -PC  
>   **[Komodo IDE](http://komodoide.com/download/)** -MAC 
>   or any other text editor which will show `line nos`.

Tested on:

> **Joomla 3.x**

**Procedure:** 
You need to add some external `JS files` to your Joomla Admin's template. These JS files are already included with your Code Mirror plugin.

> Admin templates are located in this directory : `/administrator/templates`

If your default Admin template is `isis`, the file you need to edit is :

`/administrator/templates/isis/index.php`

Similarly if your default style is different, you need to edit its respective `index` file.

**Step 1 :**
Add this code anywhere inside the `<head> --- </head>` tags of your `index.php`.

```
<script src="/media/editors/codemirror/mode/php/php.js"></script>
<script src="/media/editors/codemirror/addon/edit/matchbrackets.js"></script>
<script src="/media/editors/codemirror/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
<script src="/media/editors/codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
<script src="/media/editors/codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="/media/editors/codemirror/mode/clike/clike.js"></script>
```

> Ideally you should add it below `line 178` :

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="<?php echo JUri::root(true); ?>/media/jui/js/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

**Step 2 :** Create a variable having our desired CodeMirror config in JSON format
The file you need to edit for this is : `/plugins/editors/codemirror/layouts/editors/codemirror/elements.php`

Add this `$myoptions` variable to your `elements.php`

```
$myoptions = '{
               "autofocus": true,
               "lineWrapping": true,
               "styleActiveLine": true,
               "lineNumbers": true,
               "gutters": ["CodeMirror-linenumbers", "CodeMirror-foldgutter", "CodeMirror-markergutter"],
               "foldGutter": true,
               "markerGutter": true,
               "mode": "application/x-httpd-php",
               "matchBrackets": true,
               "autoCloseTags": true,
               "matchTags": true,
               "scrollbarStyle": "native",
               "vimMode": false
           }';
```

> Ideally you should place it just below `line 20`:

```
$buttons = $displayData->buttons;
```

**Step 3:** Then you need to replace this line of the same `elements.php`:
 [originally this was present at `line 24` but after you add `$myoptions` variable it must have shifted to somewhere around `line 40`.]

```
var id = ' . json_encode($id) . ', options = ' . json_encode($options) . ';
```

with this :

```
var id = ' . json_encode($id) . ', options = ' . $myoptions . ';
```

*That's it. You're good to go. Check out these screens below:*

**-------------------------Before-------------------------**

[image]
**-------------------------After-------------------------**

[image]

These files might may get overwritten if you update your Joomla.
Keep backup of both these files.

PHP plugin used : [**Sourcerer**](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer)
Line no reference : **[NotePad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.1.html)**

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you can set the right syntax in a parameter array.

On the associative array `$params`, set the `syntax` key equal to the value `php`.

This will do it:

```
$params['syntax'] = 'php';

$editor = JEditor::getInstance('codemirror');
echo $editor->display('name_of_element', $value, '100%', 900, '300', '3', false, null, null, null, $params);
```

Comment: Sorry for the short answer but the solution I propose is by far easier to implement than the other ones and need no overwriting of any Joomla plugin.